# Why is this specific PowerShell command failing in .NET 6 (it used to work in .NET 4)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have a project using this code

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo");
var NetAdapters = ps.Invoke();
```

This code works perfectly in a .NET 4.7.2 project, but after converting to .NET 6 (net6.0-windows), it throws this exception at runtime when executing the `Invoke()` line:

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I tested the same code with the command `get-help` to make sure that PowerShell was able to execute - and it succeeded. Only this specific `get-netadapterhardwareinfo` is failing, and it does work in my local PowerShell as well as with .NET 4.7.2.

These are the references I added for the project (note that it builds perfectly fine)

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Any reason this is failing? Any workaround or something I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) commented, you need to import [NetAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) module:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "NetAdapter");
ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo");
var result = ps.Invoke();
```

But this may return zero results. I think, environment was not initialized or blocked. For tests, you can create a new session with unrestricted policies for PowerShell runspace.

```
Collection<PSObject> result;
InitialSessionState state = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
state.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(state))
{
  runspace.Open();
  using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(runspace))
  {
    ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "NetAdapter");
    ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo");
    result = ps.Invoke();
  }
  runspace.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried the first chunk of code before, but it never worked, the import module was being restricted and I wasn't able to make it through. I was able with your second block of code. Is there any downside on using this InitialSessionState?

Comment: I guess, not. Because `InitialSessionState` is used for startup configuration PowerShell commands. Here, you can define third party modules using `ImportPSModule` method, sets thread options, variables, cmdlets, provider and etc.